# Гномы и dwarf

Tags: литература, переводы, история

В английской мифологии есть два типа карликов, различных и по виду, и по поведению: гномы-волшебники вроде Оле'Лукойе или гнома из сказки о полёте Нильса на гусе, и гномы-рудокопы, вроде Гимли из "Властелина колец". По-английски первых называют "gnome", а вторых "dwarf".

Есть ли в русском языке литературном языке наименования разделяющие данных существ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Названия мифологических существ как правило не переводятся. Правда так как дворфы это общегерманский эпос, то в России их узнали сперва из сказок братьев Грим, соответственно в научной литературе более распространённым является немецкое заимствование **цверг** (Белоснежка гостила как раз у них). Этот же вариант зафиксирован и в большинстве словарей. До ХХ века и гномов и дворфов называли ещё **карлами**, или **карликами**, но название не прижилось. В геймерской среде распространённей будут варианты **дворф** и **дварф**. В литературных переводах, если не требуется противопоставления, оба варианта переводят **гномом**, если этих существ противопоставить нужно, то варианты самые разнообразные, вплоть до польских **краснолюдей**.

В целом, литературная норма перевода английского dwarf'а - это **цверг** или **гном**, хотя  называть их **дворфами** тоже вполне допустимо.

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, в русском языке их быть не может, потому что в нашем фольклоре подземные жители маленького роста называются чудь белоглазая. Поэтому в данном случае мы можем опираться только на западное деление.
Насколько я помню, гномы и дварфы — это не совсем одно и то же, хоть и близкие расы.

Comment: Помнится, читал на одном сайте, там чудь белоглазую сравнивали не гномами, а с эльфами из творчества Толкина. Дивный народ (так назывались эльфы у Толкина) -- чудь. Под горой жил в "Хоббите" король эльфов Трандуил. 

Я не спорю с вашим утверждением. Сказки трактуют по разному. Вот вспомнил ещё такую трактовку.

Comment: @Nikolja, в скандинавской мифологии гномы - это тёмные родственики эльфов, свартальвы (тёмные эльфы).

Comment: Дело в том, что чудь маленького роста, а средний рост эльфа выше человеческого.

Answer (score 4):

"Дворфы" давно вошло в обиход. Спасибо геймерам и прочим любителям фэнтэзи.
Во всяком случае мне бы в голову не пришло переводить dwarf как гном.
Тут скорее можно гадать о том, почему первые, гномы, были усвоены языком гораздо раньше. 
Возможно, они как-то пришли через французский, а дворфам такое счастье не улыбнулось.

Comment: Одним из устоявшихся переводов слова dwarf является "карлик". Например, его применяют в астрономии при названии типов звезд ("белый карлик", "красный карлик").

Comment: Ничего удивительного. Там дворфы противопоставляются джяйнтам (giants), перевод "гиганты и карлики" напрашивается.