# Правильно ли: "дубовая бочка <...> вина"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вкратце: имеется проект локализации одной [игры](http://bay12games.com/dwarves/).

Подстрочный перевод названий предметов (контейнеров с содержимым) даёт словосочетания вида `"дварфийское вино бочка (дубовый)"` (в оригинале что-то вроде `"dwarven wine barrel (oaken)"`). Есть программа, частично исправляющая перевод и приводящие подобные словосочетания к виду `"дубовая бочка дварфийского вина"`. Есть мнение одного человека, что это словосочетание лучше бы звучало в виде `"дубовая бочка с дварфийским вином"`, я же считаю, что и в текущем виде вполне благозвучно и вполне соответствует нормам русского языка (я глобально не вижу отличия от словосочетаний типа "бокал вина" и "рюмка водки", или, скажем, "коробка сладостей"). Технически можно реализовать и второй вариант (как и варианты типа "бочка с дварфийским вином (дубовая)"), тут скорее вопрос, нужно ли в данном случае что-то менять?

Хотелось бы услышать мотивированные мнения, какой вариант лучше и/или правильнее?

Answer (score 1):

Разница между этими двумя сочетаниями в том, что при беспредложным варианте подразумевается мера, в то время как предлог с указывает на содержимое.В вашем варианте лучше использовать беспредложную конструкцию, т.к. такие конструкции при переводе обычно получают беспредложную конструкцию. Второй вариант был бывозможен, если бы было написано: oaken barrel with wine.

Comment: "подразумевается мера" - в смысле акцент на контейнере, а не на содержимом?

Comment: В беспредложном варианте (дубов. бочка дварфийского вина) номинировано само вино с его мерой; в варианте с предлогом (дуб. бочка с дварф. вином) — заполненная нормированная тара, и вино здесь есть лишь частный случай содержимого. В обоих вариантах, по-моему, подрывную роль в виде и понимании играет эпитет "дубовый", который в данном русскоязычном случае имеет значение не большее, чем другие характер-ки, напр., форма или цвет. В качестве нейтрального термина предмета (контейнера с содержимым), как факта его наличия, я бы выбрал 2-й вариант. А для случая меры веселящего напитка к обеду — 1-й.

Comment: В беспредложной конструкции акцент ставятся на мере емкости а в предложной конструкции  - на контейнер, сосуд, который чем-то заполнен.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того, что "dwarven" — это "гномий", а русского слова "двоф" нету.
Я бы выбрал Ваш, первый, вариант, но мотивировать сложно. Могу сказать, что в словосочетании "дубовая бочка с гномьим вином" акцент делается на содержимом, и он, как мне кажется, совсем необязателен.

Comment: По поводу перевода слова dwarf было уже немало споров, вообще это довольно больная тема в русскоязычном сообществе. Самый простой ответ - в игре есть раса gnomes. Разница в том, что dwarf - это низкорослый богатырь, а gnome - полуразумное тщедушное существо, любитель красть выпивку и припасы (http://dfwk.ru/Mountain_gnome)

Comment: Ну, это только в одной игре такая интерпретация.) Я не смею утверждать, что говорить двофы однозначно неправильно, это уж как сложится, только всё-таки лучше обходиться своими словами или уж давно прижившимися иностранными, если возможно.

Comment: Есть еще как минимум одна литературная и игровая вселенная, где есть существа, которых по идее на русский нужно переводить как гномов, но нельзя, потому что гномы там тоже есть, да и название прижилось: http://vedmak.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8B

Comment: Так dwarfs — это и есть краснолюды?

Comment: Со 100% точностью утверждать нельзя, но по общему описанию схожи. В польском, судя по всему, krasnolud (https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasnolud) - это аналог dwarf, а krasnoludek (https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasnoludek) - аналог gnome.

Comment: В русской литературной и научной традиции дворфов переводят как **гномов** или **цвергов**. Подробнее иожно посмотреть в обсуждавшемся  вопросе по ссылке http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24326/Гномы-и-dwarf а